# Tooltips for Reactable Cells

Tags: html, r, tooltip, reactable

I was wondering if there would be a way to include tooltips for each cell in my reactable table. Currently I have a table that displays p-values for certain survey questions and demographic variables. I would like the tooltips to display the sample size for each combination. My tables look like this:

p_val

```
Demographic   Q1     Q2
Gender        .05    .12
Age           .16    .82
```

sample_size

```
Demographic   Q1     Q2
Gender        30     15
Age           45     67
```

My code currently has:

```
reactable(p_val %>% select(Demographic, everything()),
      defaultColDef = colDef(
  header = function(value) gsub(".", " ", value, fixed = TRUE),
  cell = function(value) format(value, nsmall = 1)
)
```

Is it possible to include the tooltips in the defaultColDef, and if so, would I be able to use the values from the sample_size table for these? The code I would hope would look something like:

```
tooltip = list(formatting_options, data = sample_size %>% select(Demographic, everything()))
```

Comment: There is documentation for adding tool tips to reactable() athttps://glin.github.io/reactable/articles/cookbook/cookbook.html#tooltips-1

Comment: @SusanSwitzer Thanky you! Unfortunately those tooltips are for the column headers, I was hoping for something for the cells themselves that displayed sample size. This would also mean that I wouldn't be able to hard-code in the values for the tooltips, as is in the documentation.

Comment: Take a look at this GitHub issue which explains how to add toltips for the cells https://github.com/glin/reactable/issues/220